# Buildconf not found when compiling php on windows

Tags: php, windows, build

I am trying to compile PHP on a windows 10 by following below instructions

https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2

All steps are ok until I try to perform the buildconf step.
In that moment the phpsdk console returns a simple: "'buildconf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Is buildconf a part of SDK right? What can it make not to be found? I was expeting it to be reacheable from inside the SDK itself...

I am trying to compile it in a windows 10 VM under Paralells Dekstop (MacOSX) but that should not be a problem right?

Versions used:

- Visual Studio 2017 Community
- PHP 7.3.1
- Windows 10 Professional 64 bit

Any thing that I miss?

Comment: This is more of a sysadmin question. You should try asking over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: thanks. I have just asked on Server Fault.